# sshd: error: connect_to XXXXXXXX: unknown host

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, openssh, sshd, socks5

I am trying to create SOCKS proxy server using:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -D 8123 -f -C -N proxy@us-vpn.dennas
```

It seems to mostly work, however in log I see following errors:

```
Feb 22 08:42:41 us-vpn sshd[5383]: error: connect_to kjtragwzsp: unknown host (Name or service not known)
Feb 22 08:42:42 us-vpn sshd[5383]: error: connect_to rpqdytei: unknown host (Name or service not known)
Feb 22 08:42:43 us-vpn sshd[5383]: error: connect_to xdnomil: unknown host (Name or service not known)
```

Could someone please advice what could the cause be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating SOCKS proxy, you forward the traffic from your browser over the secure tunnel and the remote server is connecting to the target hosts for you.

In case you type to your browser `kjtragwzsp`, the proxy server tries to connect to that hostname and if that hostname is not known, it reports this error. No more no less.

Comment: So basically it means there is some issue with the website I'm viewing, not with my proxy setup? Glad to hear, thanks :)

Comment: Yes. There is nothing wrong with the proxy. Either user or website is trying to access unknown hostname for some reason.